# How to Enable Drag and Drop of Files from Windows Explorer into a .NET MAUI Application?

Tags: drag-and-drop, maui

I'm developing an application using .NET MAUI and I'm interested in implementing a drag and drop feature where users can drag files from Windows Explorer (or Finder on macOS, etc.) and drop them into my MAUI application. I have used this feature in the past with Windows Forms and WPF applications, but I'm having trouble finding information on how to implement it in a MAUI application.

I understand that MAUI provides support for dragging and dropping elements within an application using the DragGestureRecognizer and DropGestureRecognizer classes. However, I'm specifically looking for a way to drag files from the file system and drop them into my application, similar to the DragDrop and DragEnter events in Windows Forms and WPF.

Does anyone know if this is currently possible in MAUI and, if so, how to implement it? Any help or pointers towards relevant documentation or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6080). Won’t work until this is fixed. Currently in Backlog.